# Create Group Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, rest, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a question concerning the Microsoft Graph API.
I try to create a group via REST API call within a C# program and I keep getting an "Unauthorized" error.

- I have created an Azure Web App.
- I have set the permission for the GraphAPI to: "Read and write all Groups"
- I have the clientID and clientSecret
- I have the tenantID
- I get a working token from the GetTokenForApplication Method.

I get the "unauthorized" error message right after: HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(groupsEndpoint, createBody);

What could be wrong?

```
public static async Task<string> CreateGroupAsync(string groupName) {
        JObject jResult = null;
        string createdGroupId = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var token = AuthenticationHelper.GetTokenForApplication();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            //I have removed the tenantID
            Uri groupsEndpoint = new Uri(Constants.GraphResourceUrl + "THIS_IS_WHERE_MY TENANT_ID_WOULD_BE/groups");


            string postBody = "{'mailEnabled':true," 
                            + "'displayName':'Group " + groupName + "',"
                            + "'mailNickName':'" + groupName + "',"
                            + "'securityEnabled':false," 
                            + "'groupTypes':unified" 
                            + "}";

            var createBody = new StringContent(postBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(groupsEndpoint, createBody);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                jResult = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
                createdGroupId = (string)jResult["id"];
                MessageBox.Show("Created group: " + createdGroupId);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("We could not create a group. The request returned this status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show("We could not create a group: " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        return createdGroupId;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116473/graph-api-401-unauthorised

Comment: Great! Thank you, that worked. I had to then reorder the postBody. But with using "https://graph.microsoft.com" as the resource for acquiring the token that was the solution.

Comment: Glad that it helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph Api - 401 Unauthorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116473/graph-api-401-unauthorised)